# How to access pagination url without query string in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to access pagination URL without query string in CodeIgniter like

> http://127.0.0.1/hmvc/business_list/20

Now I am getting URL like

> http://127.0.0.1/hmvc/business_list/?p=2

By this I am unable to read the URL segment and pagination is not working fine. It should return 0-10 records on the first page and 10-20 on second page and so on. But in my case, it returns 0-10 on the first page then 2-12 on the second page on the basis of URL segment.

Here is my code:

```
public function index()
{
    $query = $this->db->get('categories','10',$this->uri->segment(2));
    $data['results'] = $query->result();
    $data['seg'] = $this->uri->segment(2);
    $query2 = $this->db->get('categories');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'business_list/';


     $config['total_rows'] = $query2->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;
  //  $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri->segment(2);
   // $config['page_query_string'] = false;
    $config['page_query_string'] = true;
    $config['full_tag_open'] = "<ul class='pagination pagination-right margin-none'>";
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>";
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tagl_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tagl_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['title'] = "Business List";

    $this->load->view('categories',$data);
   }
```

How do I rectify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use below configuration for pagination

```
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;

$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination pagination-right margin-none">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class='disabled'><li class='active'><a href='#'>';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '<span class='sr-only'></span></a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```